# Test if a Dart value is actually a function?

Tags: function, types, dart

Is it possible to test if a value is a function that can be called? I can test for null easily but after that I have no idea how to ensure the parameter passed in is actually a function?

```dart
void myMethod(funcParam)
{
   if (funcParam != null)
   {
       /* How to test if funcParam is actually a function that can be called? */
       funcParam();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```dart
void myMethod(funcParam) {
    if(funcParam is Function) {
        funcParam();
    }
}
```

Of course, the call to `funcParams()` only works if the parameter list matches - `is Function` doesn't check for that. If there are parameters involved, one can use [typedefs](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#typedefs) to ensure this.

```dart
typedef void MyExpectedFunction(int someInt, String someString);

void myMethod(MyExpectedFunction funcParam, int intParam, String stringParam) {
    if(funcParam is MyExpectedFunction) {
        funcParam(intParam, stringParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you argue that `is Function` only works without parameters?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `is Function` works fine, but the call to `funcParam()` will fail if the parameters don't match.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you want to check if the function can be called with zero arguments.

```dart
typedef NullaryFunction();

main () {
  var f = null;
  print(f is NullaryFunction);  // false
  f = () {};
  print(f is NullaryFunction);  // true
  f = (x) {};
  print(f is NullaryFunction);  // false
}
```

If you just want to know that it is some function, you can test with `... is Function`. All callable objects implement Function, but it is technically possible (though often not useful) to implement Function manually without actually being callable. It does make a kind of sense for objects that mock callability through `noSuchMethod`.

Answer (score 3):

```dart
  var f = () {};
  print(f is Function); // 'true'

  var x = (x){};
  print(x is Function); // 'true'
```