# Can I easily tell if `Function.apply` will fail due to incorrect argument count?

Tags: dart

I have some code in a web server that maps routes into handlers, like this:

```dart
final Map<String, Handler> handlers = {
  r'/index.html': StaticFileHandler('./web'),
  r'/test/(\d+)/(\d+)': MyTestHandler
};

MyTestHandler(HttpRequest request, int number1, int number2) {
  request.response.headers.contentType = new ContentType('text', 'html');
  request.response.write('<h1>$number1 ($number2)</h1>');
  request.response.close();
}
```

In order to support the regular expressions as arguments, I have to use `Function.apply` after extracting the arguments; which means no dev-time checking or routes against handlers. If you get the wrong number of regex groups vs handler arguments; it explodes like this:

```dart
Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'call'
Receiver: Closure: (HttpRequest, int) => dynamic from Function 'MyTestHandler': static.
Tried calling: call(Instance of '_HttpRequest', "2", "3")
Found: call(request, number)
Stack Trace:
```

This isn't totally obvious to the developer what went wrong; so I would rather throw a custom error that explains the issue more easily.

Is there an easy way I can detect this failure (eg. get the number of arguments a function expects) that:

1. Doesn't use something hefty like Mirrors
2. Doesn't involve catching all exceptions; as this will impede debugging, and it's possible this same error could be called from within the handler by the users handling code; and I don't want to interfere with that error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is to create some typedefs (one for each possible signature) and then check against them with `is` or you can pass the arguments as array.

This answer contains a code example https://stackoverflow.com/a/22653604/217408

(just copied)

```dart
typedef NullaryFunction();

main () {
  var f = null;
  print(f is NullaryFunction);  // false
  f = () {};
  print(f is NullaryFunction);  // true
  f = (x) {};
  print(f is NullaryFunction);  // false
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the last part means; but the typedef idea might work!

Comment: Use the same function signature for each handler like `MyTestHandler(HttpRequest request, List args)`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean about the array now. That'd lead to a slightly clumsy implementation inside each handler (verifying the count), so I'll try the other first :)

Comment: So this works; but I cant to it dynamically (not even the `is` check), so I've got 0-10 hard-coded. It means a mismatch for <= 10 args gives a nice error page; but a mismatch for 11+ fails ;O(